# Can't upload application to App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, app-store

I was recently trying to add my latest game for iPhone to the App Store, so I setup the binary and everything looked fine. Apple then had me download "Application Loader" through iTunes Connect which I did, and then opened it and uploaded the binary. After uploading, I was confronted with the following message:
"There is no embedded java executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools."
I just installed Xcode over again and nothing happened. What should I do?

I'm running 10.7 Lion on a Macbook Pro if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Lion is still under NDA. Please go to Apple's own developer forums.

Comment: I don't see how this violates the NDA... I just stated I was using the OS.

Comment: You are not allowed to talk about features, issues, etc. regarding Lion or iOS 5! Therefor nobody can help you here.

Comment: I don't see why the site as a whole should care about tangential issues such as any NDA which to be frank the OP is probably not bound by anyway.

Comment: Since developers who are under NDA cannot talk about it without violating their NDA, they can't help OP (triple negative :O ). That means the entire question will descend into speculation. OP might not be bound by the NDA, but the people who can replicate/have dealt with a similar issue won't be able to help. (Of course, there are people who grab NDA software and use it, but generally most devs can't really help)

Comment: Now that Lion is out. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade to 10.6. This will solve that issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know for sure that this is it but unlike earlier OS X versions, 10.7 does not come with a JRE installed by default.

Try installing the Apple JRE. Probably the easiest way is to attempt to run a Java program, the OS will popup a dialog and offer to install the JRE for you.

Comment: I tried this... but later just tried loading the app on a computer running Snow Leopard. It worked fine... problem solved ;)